# regex substitute html href and u tags in list (python)

Tags: python, regex

In python I have a list with string items that look like that:

```
My website is <a href="WEBSITE1" target='_blank'><u>WEBSITE1</u></a> 
The link is <a href="LINK1" target='_blank'><u>LINK1</u></a> 
...
```

And what I want to do is to substitute (in every list item) the href syntax leaving only the link as text, so my list would look like:

```
My website is WEBSITE1
The link is LINK1
...
```

I was thinking about matching and replacing this regex:

```
<a href="(.*?)" target='_blank'><u>(.*?)</u></a>
```

with:

```
(.*?)
```

but it doesn't work. It seems to complex. Any easy way to have as output a list object with cleaned items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also process the string with an HTML parser, e.g. [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) and it's `replace_with()` - finding all `a` elements in a string and replacing them with the link texts:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> l = [
...     """My website is <a href="WEBSITE1" target='_blank'><u>WEBSITE1</u></a>""",
...     """The link is <a href="LINK1" target='_blank'><u>LINK1</u></a>"""
... ]
>>> for item in l:
...     soup = BeautifulSoup(item, "html.parser")
...     for a in soup("a"):
...        a.replace_with(a.text)
...     print(str(soup))
... 
My website is WEBSITE1
The link is LINK1
```

Or, as pointed out by @user3100115 in comments, just getting the text of the "soup" object also works on your sample data:

```
>>> for item in l:
...    print(BeautifulSoup(item, "html.parser").get_text())
... 
My website is WEBSITE1
The link is LINK1
```

Comment: I think `soup.get_text()` will be fine here.

Comment: @user3100115 good point! It would also work on the provided samples. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to use a regex I would use something like

```
<a href.*?><u>(.*?)<\/u><\/a>
```

and then replace in a list comprehension

```
pattern = re.compile('<a href.*?><u>(.*?)<\/u><\/a>')
print [re.sub(pattern, r"\1", string) for string in my_list]
```

But consider using `beautifulsoup` or another html parser, as pointed out in other answers, which will provide you with a more generic solution

## Regex Explanation

- `<a href.*?>` match an `a href` tag, non greedy, up to the first closing bracket
- `<u>` match the u tag
- `(.*?)` match the string you want to keep
- `<\/u><\/a>` match the closing tags

Answer (score 0):

This regex seems to work

```
([^<]+)<a\s+href\s*=\s*"([^"]+).*
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gK1lL0/1)**

*Python Code*

```
p = re.compile(r'<a\s+href\s*=\s*"([^"]+).*')
test_str = ["My website is <a href=\"WEBSITE1\" target='_blank'><u>WEBSITE1</u></a>", "The link is <a href=\"LINK1\" target='_blank'><u>LINK1</u></a>"]

for x in test_str:
    print(re.sub(p, r"\1", x))
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/K7sFYd)**

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve the parenthesized capture group in your `re.sub`:

```
>>>s = """
My website is <a href="WEBSITE1" target='_blank'><u>WEBSITE1</u></a>
The link is <a href="LINK1" target='_blank'><u>LINK1</u></a>
"""
>>> re.sub("<a href=\"(.*?)\" target='_blank'><u>(.*?)</u></a>", r'\1', s)
'\nMy website is WEBSITE1 \nThe link is LINK1 \n'
```

Make sure the *replacement* string is a proper `r` escaped string, else it will simply replace with `\1`.

As your input is a list (let's assume its name is `s`):

```
>>> for i in range(0,len(s)):
...    s[i] = re.sub("<a href=\"(.*?)\" target='_blank'><u>(.*?)</u></a>", r'\1', s[i])
>>> s
['My website is WEBSITE1', 'The link is LINK1']
```

If done regularly or on a large list, you can compile the regex before the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify: your title says to remove html `href` tags, but in your example, you also remove the `u` tags.

Your answer can be simplified if we are guaranteed to have no other HTML tags than `a` and `u` (or if we want to remove all tags).  In this case, we can search for anything between `<` and `>`, or for anything between `<a` or `</a>` and `>`.  My answer assumes this, so it will be invalid if it is not.

```
import re
S = (
  'My website is <a href="WEBSITE1" target="_blank"><u>WEBSITE1</u></a>',
  'The link is <a href="LINK1" target="_blank"><u>LINK1</u></a>',
)
RE1 = re.compile( r"<\/?[^>]*>")
RE2 = re.compile( r"<\/?[aA][^>]*>")
for s in S:
  s1 = RE1.sub( "", s )  # remove all tags
  s2 = RE2.sub( "", s )  # remove only <a> and </a> tags
  print (s)
  print (s1)
  print (s2)
  print ("")
```

When run (python2), it produces

```
My website is <a href="WEBSITE1" target="_blank"><u>WEBSITE1</u></a> 
My website is WEBSITE1 
My website is <u>WEBSITE1</u> 

The link is <a href="LINK1" target="_blank"><u>LINK1</u></a>
The link is LINK1
The link is <u>LINK1</u>
```

first line is original string, second is with all HTML tags removed, third is with only `a` tags removed.

I did not include a third choice: only remove the `a href` tags.